# When to close SQLite database (using FMDB)

Tags: sqlite, fmdb

When should you close the connection to an SQLite database (using [db close] in FMDB)?

Right now I am closing it after running every batch of related queries, but should I rather close when my app closes? What are the pros/cons of doing either way?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061036/cocoa-sqlite-when-to-close-database


refer to this question

Comment: Okay, thanks, didn't see that. But those 2 answers have no votes/comments and don't really answer my question (what are the pros/cons)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm the guy who wrote FMDB.

Keep it open unless you change your schema.  That's the only reason to close it, and constantly re-opening it is a little hit on performance / battery life.

Comment: @ccgus Thanks.. FMDB is really good.  but may time app is crash due to this.  Error :  "database is currently in use". On each operation first i open db. than some place i close it also..   so is it good idea to close each time ?  its good to close when app is gone in backgroud mode ? Please give me suggestion... Its really appricited..

Comment: @ccgus Should we close the database when the app goes into the background?

Comment: I don't do much iOS programming- so take my answer with a grain of salt.  But no, I don't think you need to close it.  If the fd is still around in SQLite, then it should all be good.  I guess try it, and let us know what you find out :)